# Take all items with enumerable#take

Tags: ruby, enumerable

How can I Enumerable#take **all the things**?

```
arr = [1, 2, 3]
# Works
arr.take(1)
# Gives RangeError: float Inf out of range of integer
arr.take(Float::INFINITY)
# Gives RangeError: float Inf out of range of integer
arr.take(1.0/0.0)
# RangeError: bignum too big to convert into `long'
arr.take(1000_000_000_000_000_000_000_000_000_000_000_000_000_000_000_000_000)
# TypeError: no implicit conversion from nil to integer
arr.take(nil)
```

If it's not possible to take all items with Enumerable#take, then I'd have to have the convoluted code in `display_results_allowing_all_objects` rather than the simple code in `display_results`.

```
MAX_ROWS = 1

# Simple code: Only two lines long.    
def display_results(results)
  results_to_display = results.take(MAX_ROWS)
  puts results_to_display.map{|result| result.join("\t")}.join("\n")
end

results = [["Foo", 1], ["Bar", 2], ["Baz", 3]]

display_results(results)

NEW_MAX_ROWS = Float::INFINITY

# Convoluted mess: six lines long
def display_results_allowing_all_objects(results)
  results_to_display = if NEW_MAX_ROWS == Float::INFINITY
                         results
                       else
                         results_to_display = results.take(NEW_MAX_ROWS)
                       end
  puts results_to_display.map{|result| result.join("\t")}.join("\n")
end

display_results_allowing_all_objects(results)
```

Comment: do `arr.take(arr.size)`.. Did I get your question or not? :(

Comment: @ArupRakshit that'd work, but there ought to be a better way.

Comment: `enumerable#take` takes only integer as an argument..I blv..

Comment: Why do you think there has to be a better way? `Take`ing everything is effectively just calling `to_a` on it. The MRI source for the method returns `rb_ary_subseq(obj, 0, len)`. It simply creates a sub array from 0 to `len`, so Arup's answer is correct.

Comment: I'm a little confused. Doesn't `arr.take_all == arr` ? Why would you need this?

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Enumerable#take_while](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-take_while) to take all the items

```
$> arr.take_while { true }
 # => [1, 2, 3]
```

Answer (score 1):

We can do the `[0..-1]`. But with `..` you can't get *0 items* while with `...` you can't get *all of them*. If you can deal with inability to get 0 results, use `..`, but you'll have to do `-1`, so the `0` will mean the *all results*:

```
results_to_display = results[0 .. rows_to_take-1]
```

Answer (score -1):

You could cast `#to_a` which would take everything:

```
arr = [1, 2, 3]
arr.to_a
#=> [1, 2, 3]

(1..4).lazy.to_a
#=> [1, 2, 3, 4]
```

Comment: This doesn't allow me to choose either to take a limited number of items, or to take all items.

Comment: So use `to_a` when you want all of it or `take` otherwise?

Comment: Besides, your question just asked how to take everything.